# Change variable value in fail function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I am currently struggling with `$.getJSON()` and resulting `.fail()` function. I am trying to get it so that when a `$.getJSON()` fails, it changes the variables value to something else - such as:

```
var mangoes = $.getJSON("mangoesurl.com/json").fail(mangoes="{value:0}");
```

I cannot use another variable as I am also using `$.when()` later to retrieve that data from the mangoes JSON.

Does anybody know if this is possible, how I can do it or an alternative? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
var mangoes = $.getJSON("mangoesurl.com/json").fail(mangoes="{value:0}");
var mangoes2 = $.getJSON("mangoesurl.com/json2").fail(mangoes="{value:0}");
$.when(mangoes, mangoes2).then(data1, data2){

}
```

Comment: how about `return {value:0}` ?

Comment: But you also want the JSON to be saved in "mangoes", right?

Comment: @TonySamperi yes I do

Comment: @AlexBoullé which jquery version do you use ?

Comment: @user8175473 v1.11.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what you need:

```
var mangoes = $.getJSON("mangoesurl.com/json").fail(function(){
     return {value:0};
});
```

In this way *mangoes* is empty after the response. Basically this code gets the JSON but does nothing with it.
To put the JSON result into *mangoes* you need this:

```
var mangoes = $.getJSON("mangoesurl.com/json")
.success(function(response){
     return response;
});
.fail(function(){
     return {value:0};
});
```

With the When sintax you can't assign content to mangoes...you have to change the logic

```
var mangoes, mangoes2;
var deferred1 = $.getJSON("mangoesurl.com/json");
var deferred2 = $.getJSON("mangoesurl.com/json2");
$.when(deferred1, deferred2).then(function(data1, data2){
     mangoes = data1;
     mangoes2 = data2;
}, function(error){
     mangoes || mangoes = {value:0};
     mangoes2 || mangoes2 = {value:0};
});
```

Comment: The .success(), .error(), and .complete() callback methods are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use .done(), .fail(), and .always() instead.

Comment: yep. We don't know which version he's using, but this is useful.

Comment: @TonySamperi I updated my question with the $.when() statement I'm using. With adding the returns, when it fails it is not called and I'm not sure why. When they both succeed it works with the success(), but not with fail()

Comment: @TonySamperi Okay the error function works, thanks for all the help! I will mark as the correct answer, but is there a possible way to determine if only one of the mangoes fails? Thanks again, and sorry I'm quite new and bad at this stuff!

Comment: I updated the answer. {value: 0} will be assigned only if variables are empty! So if not empty you'll know the call was successful!

Comment: Thank you so much! You have really helped me a lot with this and I was quite stuck!

Comment: Glad to help! Cheers!